# Chasing pirates

Tags: mathematics, strategy, game, pursuit-evasion

You are asleep on your boat on open sea. When you wake up you discover you have been robbed. A quick inspection of security cam footage reveals that the pirates who robbed you left your ship exactly an hour ago. The sea is flat, extends indefinitely, and is fully covered in a thick persistent fog. You have no idea in which direction the pirates fled. But you do know that these pirates always continue in a straight line at full speed away from their victim. Their maximum speed on open water is 20 nautical miles per hour. Your boat can reach 21 nautical miles per hour.

How do you catch the pirates?

Comment: Can we assume that they know what is their smartest move?

Comment: @dmg - not sure what you mean by "smartest move" (the only choice the pirates have is the choice of escape direction). But your strategy should cover the worst-case scenario. (In other words: your strategy should guarantee you to catch the pirates.)

Comment: By using radar.

Comment: Catching is not defined.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If we assume the ocean is flat and extends indefinitely in all directions, there is a strategy that guarantees we can catch the pirates in at most 800,000 years.

Put our current location as the origin of a coordinate system. We will describe our position in polar coordinates, as a function of time: $(r(t),\theta(t))$ (where we have arbitrarily chosen a direction to be $\theta=0$, and $t=0$ is when we realized we had been robbed).

We begin by traveling in the $\theta=0$ direction for 20 hours, putting our position at $(420, 0)$. We are then the same distance from the origin as the pirates. Next, we will travel in a spiral, in a manner so that $r'(t)=20$ at all times. This guarantees we will always be the same distance from the origin as the pirates. For $t\geq 20$, we will have $r(t)=420+20(t-20)=20t+20$.

Our speed is
$$
\sqrt{(r')^2+r^2(\theta')^2} = 21\text{ mph},
$$
and $r'(t)=20$ for $t>20$, so
$$
\theta'(t)=\sqrt{\frac{41}{r^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{41}}{20+20t}.
$$

If there is a $t\geq 20$ for which $\theta(t)$ is the angle in which the pirates fled, we will catch them. This means we will certainly catch the pirates by the time $\theta$ has increased from $0$ to $2\pi$. If $t_0$ is the time this happens, we have
$$
2\pi=\int_{20}^{t_0}\theta'(t)\,dt=\int_{20}^{t_0}\frac{\sqrt{41}}{20+20t}dt.
$$
Solving for $t_0$ gives
$$
t_0=21\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{40\pi}{\sqrt{41}}\right)-1\approx 7,005,043,026.
$$
This means we can catch the pirates in at most 7,005,043,026 hours, or about 800 millennia. Better later than never!

Comment: Dang; same answer beat me to it moments

Comment: so, YOU can never catch the pirates. maybe one of your descendants catch theirs!

Comment: Damn, so quick!

Comment: But if you live 80 more years, you can catch the pirates with a tiny little chance of 1/10000.

Comment: How large would your range of vision have to be to achieve it in a reasonable time? (Know this is not fully specified, but hope there is an interesting conclusion)

Comment: Given this time scale, you should redo the calculation in 3D coordinates! (i.e. simulating escaping aliens from invading a peaceful galaxy)

Comment: The problem is that given 800 millennia you would never catch the pirates (*though you might catch some particles*). At open sea they (and their boat) would have already disintegrated. This is not a correct solution unless mortality and parts of thermodynamics are put on hold.

Comment: @TemplateRex This solution (and this problem) can't quite generalize that way - it would require there to be a path of finite length passing through every point on the surface of a sphere, and no such path exists. An interesting variant, which may or may not be possible, would be to allow the searchers to search a whole line (or ray) at a time - i.e. they can see infinitely far in a single direction - but then you have to limit their movement somehow and the problem would be a lot harder to state.

Comment: The nautical mile is defined as a distance on the meridian (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_mile). The meridian is an element of a globe. The polar coordinates doesn't descibe the globe geometry. So I fear the answer is wrong.

Comment: @harper regardless of exactly how fast the nautical mile is, (*whether it is 1 kilometer/hour or 10 kilometers/hour or 100000 kilometers/hour*) this answer still works because the exact distance being traveled doesn't matter - just the relative speeds (20 vs 21) and therefore the time it takes to be at the same position as the pirates.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Do you think that Kilometer/hour is a unit for a distance? Or nautical mile is a speed? `Nautical mile` != `knots`.

Comment: @harper good point, you can correct that to `how far the nautical mile is, (whether it is 1 kilometer, or 10, or 100000)` The 20 or 21 units(whatever they may be) **per hour** is still a speed however - and still doesn't change the answer.

Comment: The sea without boundaries is not exactly the earth surface. But the sea without boundaries is naturally on a globe. The used calculation is based on a planar model while it should be spheric. Therefore it should not be used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20444/discussion-between-doubledouble-and-harper).

Comment: Wouldn't it be `7,005,043,046` hours instead of `7,005,043,026` hours (since you need to account for the 20 hours you steam away from the origin)?

Comment: If you read the question you'll see this doesn't take place on a sphere but on a plane... The ocean is flat and continues endlessly in all directions

Answer (score 95):

Stay put for [about 45 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=circumference+of+the+earth+%2F+20+nautical+miles+per+hour), after which the pirates would have circumnavigated the globe and returned to your current position.

Comment: +1. Would be perfect if you included the calculation also.

Comment: A creative way to force me to sharpen the problem statement. Thx!

Comment: *"What!? We weren't expecting the pirates for another 6 days! Man the guns!!!"*

Comment: @Brendan Long - Jabe probably used miles per hour instead of nautical mile per hour.

Comment: I was going to write the same thing. Stupid pirates. One other solution I was thinking was going in some kind of an efficient spiral but couldn't proceed further.

Comment: Yup, I did not use nautical mph.  This answer is invalid now after the question has been edited to specify an endless flat ocean.

Comment: This kind of answer I feel is [negative for the site](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/lets-get-critical-nov-2014-site-self-evaluation/1621#1621).

Comment: If "continuing in a straight line" means that the pirates maintain a constant bearing, then they probably will never return to the current position (they'll end up spiraling closer and closer to a pole.) What "straight line" means is a little tricky on a globe.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn the question specified very particularly that the sea has no boundary, which makes this a very reasonable answer. That is, the special case was built into the question, unlike the [transparent die](//meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1621).

Comment: @kundor I agree it's tricky. But "straight line" to a geometer, at least, would have to mean geodesic. If the world were a sphere, then, the pirates would return to whence they came. It's not quite a sphere, so I'm not sure whether they would.

Comment: @msh210 The OP edited the question *after* this question was submitted and therefore this is a valid submission.

Answer (score 22):

Drive 20 hours in a direction we will denote with as having $\theta=0$.  Drive in a spiral pattern such that you are $20t+20$ nautical miles away from you starting position.  $t$ is time in hours from right this second.

After 20 hours, your distance from the starting position will be $r=20t+20$ while your angle will be... more difficult to find.  If we assume the spiral is of the form $r = ae^{b\theta}$, $a=420$ and $b\theta = \ln\frac{t+1}{21}$.  The arc length for such a curve is $s = a\sqrt{1+b^2}e^{b\theta}/b=r\sqrt{1+b^2}/b$.  The derivative of this with respect to t is $21=v=20\sqrt{1+b^2}/b$.  This means $b = \frac{20}{\sqrt{41}}$.

$$\theta = \frac{\sqrt{41}}{20}\ln\frac{t+1}{21}$$

For $\theta =2\pi$ then $t=7005043026$ hours

Comment: Upvote as consolation prize!

Comment: "you starting position" -> *your* starting position

Answer (score 10):

Assuming there is no wind, your boat was completely still on the water before it was boarded by pirates, the pirates stepped off your boat at its center of gravity, and the pirates used motorized boats, the escape vector of the pirates will be the exact opposite of the direction your boat will be drifting in once they "step off" your boat after robbing you.

Like when you step off a boat in real life, the boat is pushed in the opposite direction that you leave it.

Comment: Haha great idea! +1

Comment: I don't believe that this necessarily hold true.  It seems that if the pirate's ship was along side of your vessel, their exiting steps, providing opposite momentum to your boat, would be toward their own ship, but their direction of departure could still be toward the front or back of your boat, or anywhere in between (somewhere around 180 degrees.)

Answer (score 4):

Wait 22.5 days, one minute and twenty seconds. By this time, the pirates are on the opposite point on the globe (assuming it's Earth) and they have stopped, because there is no way they could go away from you. Then choose a random direction. As the pirates always go away from you, they choose the same direction as you have. After 454 days, you will meet and the booty is yours!

Answer (score -1):

Since you were initially at rest, apply the [law of conservation of momentum](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/Lesson-2/Momentum-Conservation-Principle):

Initially, (boat + money) have velocity 0.

After being robbed, money has velocity 21 mph and boat has velocity `v` in the exact opposite direction.

Since the mass of the boat is a lot higher than the mass of the money,`v` is very small, however is it non-zero. Throw the anchor in the water, it will eventually come at rest at the bottom of the sea. Then, wait for a couple of hours and see in which direction does your boat stray from the anchor. Then take the anchor back and go in the opposite direction. You will catch the pirates in `20 * (1 + wait_time_in_hours)` total time.

Comment: This is identical to an answer from over a year ago, and is invalid for the same reason as that one, which comments pointed out.